# How do if fix my syntax error in using EB INIT in project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

[This is my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBXKv.png) I already have Git, python, and virtualEnv installed.

I went through https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup

When I put which EB it returned a path, but when I put EB --version I was thrown an error

it's supposed to return the EB CLI version with the python version

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198). If you want to keep your user ID secret, just replace it with some other string.